# android canvas - how can i make partitions in circle

Tags: android, canvas

I have a question related to drawing in canvas on android. I have drawn a ring circle (like a clock) but cannot make partitions in the circle. Does anyone know how this is possible and after making partitions can I make further partitions within each partition and make it link to a pop up image?

Thanks.

Comment: you should see the API demo example

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, yet what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi there, I have made a flat circle but now want to place partitions in it and make partitions like a clock...any idea?